# How to do df.to_sql using SQL Server in Azure

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, azure

I can do a df.to_slq on my local instance of SQL Server just fine. I am getting stuck when trying to do the same df.to_sll using Python and Azure SQL Server. I thought it would essentially be done like this.

```
import urllib.parse
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'Driver=%s;' % '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' +
    'Server=%s,1433;' % 'ryan-server.database.windows.net' +
    'Database=%s;' % 'ryan_sql_db' +
    'Uid=%s;' % 'UN'  +
    'Pwd={%s};' % 'PW' +
    'Encrypt=no;' +
    'TrustServerCertificate=no;'
    )

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + params
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
        
connection = engine.connect()
connection

all_data.to_sql('health', engine, if_exists='append', chunksize=100000, method=None,index=False)
```

That is giving me this error.

```
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO health ([0], [Facility_BU_ID], [Code_Type], [Code], [Description], [UB_Revenue_Code], [UB_Revenue_Description], [Gross_Charge], [Cash_Charge], [Min_Negotiated_Rate], [Max_Negotiated_Rate], etc., etc., etc.
```

I found this link today:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
```

I tried to do something similar, like this.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
df = all_data
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'ryan-server.database.windows.net'
database = 'ryan_sql_db' 
username = 'UN' 
password = 'PW' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     cursor.execute(all_data.to_sql('health', cnxn, if_exists='append', chunksize=100000, method=None,index=False))
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

When I run that, I get this error.

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

What I'm really hoping to to is `df.to_sql`, not `Insert Into`.  I am working in Spyder and trying to send the data from my local machine to the cloud.

Comment: Have you allowed your IP Address through the Azure Firewall?

Comment: Right now, there appears to be no firewall setup. With no firewall in place, and my login creds inserted into params, I would think that's enough for this thing to work, but I don't really know. Are you saying I need to setup a firewall for this process to run?

Comment: please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure , otherwise all external access is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the two links below, and got it working.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-database-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current
- https://www.virtual-dba.com/blog/firewalls-database-level-azure-sql/

Basically, you need to open your command window on your local machine, enter 'ipconfig', and grab two IP addresses. Then, enter those into SQL Server in Azure.

```
EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule 
N'health', 
'192.0.1.1', 
'192.0.0.5';
```

Finally, run the small script below, in SQL Server, to confirm that the changes were made correctly.

```
USE [ryan_sql_db]
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.database_firewall_rules
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```